# Eliminating an earth / ground loop in an A/V set-up

Tags: ground-loop, power-amplifier

I have an A/V system with two active sub-woofers.

One is close to the amplifier connected with a 1m RCA cable. Its mains connection is into the same power strip as the amplifier.  There will be an earth loop but it is short and it does not add a significant amount of noise.  Update, I now know that the amp is not directly earthed but it may be through one of the other devices.

The second sub is further away and is connected with a 10m RCA cable.  It is not actually that far but the cable needs to go around the wall and not across the floor.   7m would be sufficient but that is not a commonly available length.  I tried a 5m cable with a 2m extension but it was not noticeably better.  The mains for this sub is close to the sub and hence not close to amp.  This earth loop is much larger and picks up a significant hum which I would like to eliminate.

Further evidence that the problem is an earth loop:

1. The hum is stopped if the signal cable is disconnected.  I tested by disconnecting the at the sub end.  My initial concern was that there was a fault within the sub.  I have tried disconnecting the signal cable at the amp end. Initially, I got a worse hum but when I shorted out the loose end, this went away.
2. If I feed a signal from a battery powered iPod, there is no hum.  The iPod was connected with a short cable.  I'll test with a longer cable along a similar route to the usual signal cable and update later.
3. Temporarily breaking the supply earth while connected to the amp also stops the hum.

All plugs are three pin and connected to grounded sockets.  It is possible that the earth is not used but test 3 suggests that the sub is certainly grounded.  I could repeat test 3 but break the earth at the amp end as an additional test.  Most of the plugs are sealed and not easy to inspect.

So, a simple and effective but maybe not safe and legal solution is to break the supply earth.  I would like to find a better solution.

I found this item on Amazon: [AV Link Ground Loop Isolator](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000NVWB9O/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1).  Cheap and easy to fit.  I feared that it might attenuate the signal and cause harmonic distortion but a quick test using test tones from my iPod and my ear to judge suggested that it was not too bad.  However, when I connected it with the amp, it actually made the problem far worse rather than better.  I guess that it contains a transformer which was picking up more hum than the earth loop.

I found other items, e.g.  [PAC SNI-1 Noise Isolator](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/PAC-SNI-1-Noise-Isolator/dp/B000K50HJE/ref=sr_1_9?crid=19RUTJJ5OZCTP&dchild=1&keywords=earth%20loop%20isolator&qid=1591436823&s=electronics&sprefix=earth%20loop%2Celectronics%2C158&sr=1-9) which did not seem to be transformer based, but the reviews were terrible so I did not even try them.

So, I am still looking for a solution and preferably not a very expensive one.  The devices above are passive but I would consider a powered device.

It is common advice to keep the signal cables away from the mains and that is already the case here but I was considering the exact opposite: power the sub from the same power strip as the amp and the other sub.  Hence, it would need an equally long power cable as the signal cable which I would run together.  The idea is that both the signal and power cable would pick up the same hum but out of phase and hence they would cancel over.  Is this worth trying or have I missed something?

I am in the UK so the supply is 230VAC 50Hz.  Since this is the UK, I expect that everything in the house is on the same phase.  In this case, both sockets are on the same breaker in the consumer unit.

The AVR is a Denon X3200W - [manual](http://manuals.denon.com/AVRX3200W/EU/EN/index.php).

The subwoofers are [BK Gemini II](https://www.bkelec.com/HiFi/Sub_Woofers/Gemini.htm)s.  I cannot find an online manual but even the supplied paper manuals are very simple.

Other devices connected to the amp are: the TV, a Tivo (digital video recorder), two disc players, a digital iPod dock, and the other sub.  The sub uses an RCA cable, the iPod dock uses an optical cable, and all others are HDMI.

All devices except the Tivo and the distant sub are powered by the same power strip.  The Tivo goes to another power strip but both strips go to the same double socket. This is partly just a matter of sockets on the strips but also one strip contains devices that can be off when no one is present and the other is for devices that should remain on: Tivo, internet router, phone base station, etc.

I have now checked the amp end of its power cable and it has a two pin connector.  So, it is not earthed and my loop must be through one of the other devices, possibly even the other sub.

Thanks to the comments, I have more ideas to try.  Annoyingly, repeats of tests that I have made before don't seem to entirely consistent.  Possible explanations of the inconsistent results are that my hearing varies and other noises vary.  E.g. sometimes I hear the hum from a fridge two rooms away more clearly than the hum from the subwoofer.  More research is required.

Comment: Is the hum stopped if the cable is disconnected at the sending end? You didn't say which end you disconnected. The iPod signal - where along the cable was this injected? Start or end?

Comment: Does the amplifier have grounded or ungrounded plug? Does the subwoofer have grounded or ungrounded plug? What other devices connect to the system and do they have grounded or ungrounded plugs? Are all devices with grounded plugs connected to grounded outlets? Are the devices connected to same mains phase or different mains phase? Which subwoower and amplifier model? Link to manuals we can read?

Comment: Transformer isolator ought to be in a (mu-metal) screened can. But try the one you've got at both ends of the cable, it may pick up less hum in the other position.

Comment: yeah, look for one with a steel-looking case if it's not metal under that black plastic

Comment: that power cable thing is worth trying if it's not going to cost you anything to try. also try locating the sub wooper near the amplifier and using ashort cable to see if the hum may have some other cause.

Comment: @Andyaka I added clarifications to the question.

Comment: @Justme I added some details to the question.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I'll try at the other end. Is such a can something that I can easily easily buy?  Is it worth trying a DIY solution of wrapping in aluminium foil?

Comment: @Jasen So, the idea has some chance of success?  As you say, it is easy and free to test but slightly disruptive (i.e. wife annoying).  If the chance is non-zero then I will try.  There are two subs and the other is near the amp.  The problem there is very slight.  If I swap the sub then the problem is fixed to the location and not the sub.

Comment: According to Denon amplifier manual, it uses a two prong mains inlet so contrary what you said it is not grounded. The subwoofer uses a three prong mains inlet so it is grounded. Now, what else is connected, to where, and how?

Comment: @Justme Interesting, I had not expected that the amp might be unearthed.  Other devices are a Tivo (digital video recorder), two disc players, a dock for the iPod, and the other sub.  All were connected but off at the time of the test.  I can try disconnecting them.  So, the loop may be more complex than I expected; it might even be through the other sub.

Comment: @Justme Being a little pedantic, I just said that the plugs are three pin and connected to grounded sockets.  This is usual for the UK.  Only a tiny number of devices use two pin plugs e.g. shavers and toothbrushes.  Depending on the device, the earth might not be connected to anything but the pin will be there.  Most modern power cables have sealed plugs so it is not easy to check.

Comment: @Justme I just checked the amp end of its power cable.  It can be detached and it is only two pin.  So, indeed, the amp is not grounded and my earth loop must be through one of the other devices. When the wife next goes out, I'll try to determine which.

Comment: Foil won't work; it'll exclude electrostatic fields, not magnetic fields. Reasonably thick mild steel (like 2 mm) would work to some extent if you have metalwork skills. But a good screened transformer from a pro audio supplier could be £20 upwards.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Because aluminium is not ferromagnetic, I guess.  Anyway, it seems that I need to do some more research and experimentation to cure this problem.

Comment: In general consumer AV receivers don't use ground. Good to add that mains is single phase. Yes, disconnecting one wire or device at a time will help determine what causes the hum. However, do as the manuals say and never connect or disconnect two devices when their mains cords are powered. For example, if you have a BD player, and only connections to it are mains input and HDMI to amplifier, disconnect BD player mains plug first before HDMI. You don't want to connect and disconnect a grounded device with ungrounded devices, or two ungrounded devices.

Comment: @Justme Thanks.  Being in the UK, I was unaware of multiple phases within a house until I started to read posts from the US.  Thanks for the warning on playing with the connections.  I always kill the whole equipment rack at the sockets before playing.  In the past, I have heard some very unpleasant noises by forgetting this.

Comment: To me the norm is three phases, so that's why I asked. It's not about noises, but killing equipment due to voltage charged in the EMI filter caps in the power supplies. If you have a multimeter you can measure unpleasant voltages and currents between equipment grounds.

Comment: @Justme I am familiar with three phases in some locations, e.g. workshops, but not domestic properties.  Long ago, the mini-computer that I used at work required a 3-phase supply.  By modern standards, it is laughable that such a thing was called mini.

Comment: @Justme I am lucky not to have ever killed any equipment by making that mistake but I am aware of the possibility.  It is quite a while since I have made that mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best sollution to remove the hum is to use all optical cables for the audio. You can buy cheap analog (RCA) to optical SPDIF and replace all audio with this (but this is only an alternative path to the grounding problem)

Comment: An interesting idea and I have half of what I need already (left over from another project): the optical to RCA part.  However, would the cheap items have a suitable frequency range for a subwoofer?

Comment: yes, no problem. If you look into this converters there are some simple chip like Texas Instruments PCM2902 (used in sound cards like Behringer UCA 202) which does everything. 
Depending on how this chip is powered you can ad new noise to the system or not, so if you found a new noise try to add some capacitor to the power supply or change the power supply.

Comment: This is cheap and promising enough that I'll try it out.  I'll need a long optical cable but I can test the idea with a short one that I already have.

Comment: I have just received a little ADC.  Together with the DAC and cables that I already have, I can try the idea.  I cannot test the subs now but I hooked it up in my office set-up between the iPod dock and a small amp. I had a choice of optical or coaxial for the interconnection.  RCA is useful as I can use the cable already in place.  Even with a long RCA cable between the two, music sounds okay.  I played some test tones through it and I could not detect attenuation above 20Hz.  I could not test below that as this system does not cope even without these extra components.

Comment: You need to choose optical. With coaxial electric connection between earths remains the same with the noise.
Edit: noise floor of the signal is lower as signal is digital. But if you want to remove all electrical connection you need to use optical

Comment: Yes, that occurred to me later: the ADC and the DAC might connect the earth in to the earth out.  I plan to test tomorrow.  I have a spare optical cable for the test but it's not long enough for installation.  If it is successful then I will buy a longer one.

Comment: You are right, the coaxial interconnect did not solve the problem: neither the ADC nor the DAC broke the earth. However, with an optical connection, it was perfect.  It was even better than RCA with a broken supply earth to the sub.  I hit one problem: there was a new noise but I traced that: I had powered the ADC from the same USB supply as a nearby Raspberry Pi; switching to it own supply solved this.  Now, I just need a longer optical cable to achieve a wife approved solution. A perfect solution: cheap, low priced, and effective.  I could not detect any attenuation at low frequencies.

Comment: yes, the power supply needs to be clean enough. You can try with different power supplies. If some noise remains: try with some LC filter, or go for a linear power supply

Comment: I think that it as good as it can get now.  When there is no (deliberate) signal, I can only hear anything from the sub if I turn it on its side (it is downfiring) and put my ear really close to the speaker.  Obviously, this is not a normal listening arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

you may reduce the hum, using power cables that have rapid-rotation twists of the hot/return pair. This fast rotation of the magnetic fields will reduce the induced voltage in all nearby wiring loop.

The density of twists will increase the self-cancellation of magnetic fields, even for small short audio cables or small regions of your PCB boards.

To evaluate this, get apiece of sheet steel, tie it to GROUND with a flexible wire (to ensure it will not become an electric_field radiator) and experiment.

- Hold the sheet next to aggressor wiring --- hidden power wiring inside the walls, or near power cords running to your AV setup or near power transformers inside your AV boxes.
- Hold the sheet near your victim wiring (coax cables?) or audio Preamplifier boxes.

Ohhh ensure all your audio cables have grounds running end-to-end.

Comment: I don't recall seeing that, at least not for a very long time, but I'll look out for some.  However, I won't be able to change the wiring in the house which will be part of the problem.  The signal cable might still pick up interference from the fixed wiring.

Answer (score 0):

Hum in AV systems is often related to antenna or (old coaxial) network, cable TV or other signal cables connected to the system. Those cables bring a 2nd or 3rd ground connection to the amplifiers' ground.

Comment: I am familiar with those issues but I don't think that they apply here.  I could test by disconnecting all devices except the amp and the sub but that breaking the earth for the sub solves the problem (test 3) seems to confirm that the issue is caused by the loop between the amp and the sub.

Comment: Update.  The loop will not be between the amp and the sub as I now know that the amp is not earthed.  The loop may be between the sub and another device connected to the amp, maybe even the other amp.

Comment: A mistake in my last comment.  It should end: "maybe even the other sub".  There is only one amp and I now know that it is not earthed,